# Visual Studio Editor does not underline errors anymore

Tags: visual-studio, editor, underline

My Visual Studio (2008) Editor has stopped to underline Errors (this nifty wavy red lines). I can't really tell when, but it can be related to the installation of .Net Framework 3.5 SP 1 or the MVC Beta (which I guess is unlikely). Furthermore have I installed and uninstalled both CodeRush and Resharper for evaluation purposes (decided not to keep either one of them).

Does anyone know the problem and how to restore this functionality again?

Comment: I recently encountered the same problem with VS 2010. And I noticed it soon after, guess what, I installed and uninstalled Resharper.

Comment: It happened to me on VS2013 after installing Resharper. I think the Visual Studio Power Tools may have had an effect too.

Comment: In my case errors like this (and more) keep cropping up because I'm using VS inside a virtual machine and found my time synch was way off (by a few days!). Whenever I fix the date, they go away. Interestingly, I remember a similar issue when first using VS back in 2006.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Have you checked <kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Options...</kbd>→<kbd>Text Editor</kbd>→<kbd>C#</kbd>→<kbd>Advanced</kbd>→<kbd>Underline errors in the editor</kbd>?

I usually like to reset my settings after messing around with plugins, as they tend to mess with settings: <kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Import and Export Settings...</kbd>→<kbd>Reset all settings</kbd>.

Comment: Same fix worked for VS2013 after doing the above plus a compile.

Comment: i had to do it in 2012 and 2013. why would this be turned off by default!!

Comment: this was really helpful after I uninstalled Resharper.

Comment: I also needed to check "Show live semantic errors" in the same location

Comment: For cpp file, still its not showing red underline for errors. Do you know any way for this?

Comment: Got it ! refer [Enabling red underline for errs in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236399/i-lost-the-squiggly-red-underline-feature)

Comment: Does not work in VS 2008. (c#) Misspelled method names are not being detected right away as errors :(

Comment: I had to turn off 'Underline errors in the editor' and turn it on back and it started working. (vs2012)

Comment: Worked for Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Comment: VS2019: Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Show error squiggles

Answer (score 20):

**About possible causes.**

For VS 2012 and 2013 if you have more than one instance of Visual Studio on different machines binded to one "live" account and have installed ReSharper on one of them, it disables the native IntelliSense and error underlines (to replace by it's own rules) that will be synchronised through your account to another machine without ReSharper.

Comment: This worked for fixing my continual underline errors and xaml intellisense settings getting unset, very helpful thanks!

Comment: Dude... I just figured this out. That's spooky as hell sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

Found it in Visual Studio 2019 as: `Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Show error squiggles`

Answer (score 4):

For visual studio 2017 act according to HeeJae's comments in:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/113112/design-time-error-checking-isnt-working.html

i.e:

Hi. you are probably hitting a known issue. can you try this?

1.Update to latest release If that doesn’t solve it

2.Go to Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\General and uncheck “Allow parallel project initialization”.

3.Close VS.

4.Delete the “.vs” directory beside their solution file.

5.Reopen VS.

..

thank you

You can re-enable the "Allow parallel project initialization" option after the issue was solved.

I tried to upgrade VS, reset VS settings, clear VS cache and everything people do conventionally but none of them solved this issue! At the end the mentioned solution worked for me magically.

Good luck

Comment: Awesome thanks - this was being a right pain (vs2019)

Answer (score 3):

This is generally called **Disable Squiggl**y or Wavy lines in Visual Studio.

**How you will do in Visual studio 2013?**

**TOOLS** -> **Options**... -> **Text Editor** -> **C/C++** -> **Advanced** -> **Disable Squiggles**: **True/False** (Under IntelliSense) -> Press **OK**

Comment: You do have to wonder who would not want to show their error squiggles!

Answer (score 3):

I know its an old question, and with various solutions, but I have fixed it in different way. I'm working with Unity3D on my C# code using VS2017, when suddenly VS decides to stop underlining error while im typing. However, if I close the file tab and reopen, it suddenly undelines the error.

For example:

```
class A { 
public int x; 
s;
}
```

should obvsiouly give an error for that lonely 's' symbol. But, VS doesn't underline it until I close and reopen this file tab.

**Solution**:
Copied the entire Unity Project folder (which is like a regular VS Solution folder basically) and worked with the new folder, which issue was gone there.

Answer (score 3):

Unloading and loading same project again from the solution does the trick. Just right click on the project and click "Unload Project". Once unloaded, again right click the same project and click "Reload Project". Error highlighting will return.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with 2017. There was a 'disable intelisense' option, make sure that is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone wondering in 2021..

search for "*C_Cpp.errorSquiggles*" in the settings.

Make sure to have it active for the user, *as well as the workspace*.
No need to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you are referring to VSCode on VS. I did try searching for that in options of VS2019 and didn't find that string.

Answer (score 1):

For me (VS 2019) , after trying the other answers also, setting the scope of analysis from "Current document" to Open document" brought back the missing error markers [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just go to settings and search for errors and [Image in Error Squiggles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS9eO.png). You can see the Error squiggles (Modified: Workspace - Right now you can't see it because I modified it). Just click on modified and you will see the disabled option. If by mistake you disabled it, just enable it and you can see the red line errors again in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In latest edition, check for .vscode folder in same project folder. There will be a setting.json file in that. Delete the key value pair of `"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled"`. Restart the vs code.