# Visual Studio doesn't show me the red squiggle Intellisense errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax, syntax-error

When I'm writing code, and i purposely write a syntax error like:

```
Console.WriteLine(;
```

Visual Studio **doesn't** show me the red **squiggle** Intellisense errors.

**But when i start the program** it shows the error. That's not how it should work.

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Which IDE do you use? What is your IDE configuration?

Comment: Do you see the little red underline squiggles beneath the above line?  Check VS Options to ensure _Intellisense_ is not disabled.

Comment: @MickyD no it doesnt show that, thats the problem

Comment: @Fka im using Visual Studio

Comment: if you use VS - might need to reinstall it. It should produce little red underline

Comment: If it is Visual Studio **2015**, probably you need to clear cache or even reinstall it. Sometimes, restart helps, but it isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Ill reinstall it then

Comment: Before you go off and re-install, just try to _[reset VS settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx)_ first.  There are a few other ways to reset VS on SO too

Comment: Do you mean it will run? Or when you press f5 it will show error and it doesn't run?

Comment: @MickyD i tryed to [Reset all Options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267843/visual-studio-editor-does-not-underline-errors-anymore) and it works now. Thanks

Comment: Sweet.  Always good to know as VS takes ages to install, particularly 2015